# ECDSA signing process

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa

I am trying to learn how ECDSA works. I do not have a background in maths, but have been following a guide which has built me up from [finite fields, elliptic curves](https://github.com/jimmysong/programmingbitcoin/blob/master/). 
I am unable to figure out how a signature is generated , a description of it is [here](https://github.com/jimmysong/programmingbitcoin/blob/master/ch03.asciidoc#inscribing-the-target).

To state what i understand.

- e = private key
- G = generator point
- P = Public key
- k = Ephemeral key

The public key is a point on the curve computed as

> e.G = P

The signing algorithm starts by taking a random target R

> kG = R

The guide straight up represents R as follows (where u/v are chosen by user):

> uG + vP = kG

I sort of fail to understand how or why this relation holds true. It seems to be starting with a random point on the curve uG and it adds a scalar multiple of the public key (which could be further expressed v.e.G)

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at the [wiki page about ECDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm), and then come back with questions if anything is not clear, as your question as is, doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Ruggero , the wiki page is just plain outlining equations without providing a description as to why. This might be due to my gap in maths. Please take a look at the link (tutorial) i am on as it seems to "dumb" it down for me to understand. We choose a R and inscribe its x co-ordinate in calculation of v and msg hash/s as u.Bottom line being , the verification algo is recomputation of R based on the above values. Yet i fail to understand how the above equality holds true to begin with. i.e  a random R computed by addition of some multiple of pubkey and another random point.

Comment: I believe in your link, ecdsa is badly depicted and in my opinion it makes it much more complex, e.g. the way it throws you the $uG + vP = kG$ doesn't make sense. In the wiki you first see the signature generation, then the verification and then it explains why the verification works.

Answer (score 2):

Pick a coordinate field $\mathbb F_p$, such as $p = 2^{256} - 2^{32} - 977$.  Pick an elliptic curve over $\mathbb F_p$ of the form $y^2 = x^3 + a x + b$, such as $a = 0$ and $b = 7$.  (This is the curve secp256k1 used in Bitcoin.)  Pick a standard base point $G$ of prime order $\ell$, so that $\ell$ is the smallest positive integer such that $$[\ell]G = \underbrace{G + \cdots + G}_{\text{$\ell$ times}} = \mathcal O.$$  Here $\mathcal O$ is the ‘point at infinity’, or the identity of the group.

An ECDSA **public key** is a point $P$ on the curve with coordinates $(x(P), y(P))$.  An ECDSA **signature** on a message $m$ under $P$, is a pair $(r, s)$ of integers with $1 < r, s < \ell$ such that the **verification equation** $$r \equiv f\bigr([H(m) \, s^{-1}]G + [r s^{-1}]A\bigr) \pmod \ell$$ holds, where $f(A) = x(A) \bmod \ell$ is a kind of arbitrary function mapping the *$x$ coordinate field* $\mathbb F_p$ to the *scalar ring* $\mathbb Z/\ell\mathbb Z$ (which is a rather weird thing to do, but such is life).

The signer knows the **secret scalar** $e$ such that $P = [e]G$, in terms of which this equation is $$r = f\bigl([H(m)\,s^{-1}]G + [r s^{-1} e]G\bigr) = f\bigl([H(m) \, s^{-1} + r s^{-1} e]G\bigr),$$ which means the signer can choose a per-signature secret $k$ uniformly at random, derive $r = f([k]G)$, and then solve the scalar equation $$k \equiv H(m)\,s^{-1} + r s^{-1} e \pmod \ell$$ for $s$, by computing $$s := [H(m) \, k^{-1} + r k^{-1} e] \bmod \ell.$$